# How to surround element with div

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

How to surround element with div tag in dojo?

```
<button>Testing</button>
:
<div>
<button>Testing</button>
</div>


<div>Testing <span>something</span></div>
:
<div>
<div>Testing <span>something</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found answer

[Surrounding](http://jsfiddle.net/HwpRD/)

```
var node = domConstruct.create("div");
dojo.addClass(node,"container");
var refNode = dom.byId("refNode");
var tagName = refNode.tagName.toLowerCase();
node.innerHTML="<"+tagName+">"+refNode.innerHTML+"</"+tagName+">";
domConstruct.place(node, refNode,"before");
domConstruct.destroy(refNode);
```

Answer (score 1):

Its  pretty simple

```
 require(["dojo/dom-construct"], function(domConstruct){
      var n = domConstruct.create("div", { innerHTML: "Testing <span>something</span>" });
    });
```

read all about it [here](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/dom-construct#create)

Comment: It just creates new div with some innerHTML. It won't replaces existing one. And innerHTML for button is Testing only, what about tag name(<button>).

Comment: well you need to grab the innerhtml first in that case, then append the new markup , so lets say that you have an existing div with some markup inside, first you will copy the existing markup in a variable then replace all content of the parent with the new markup bust as an innerHTML of a div, this will wrap it inside a div as you requested.

Answer (score 1):

How about this :

```
var refNode = dom.byId("refNode");
// make the new div, with the correct class, directly after the node to be wrapped
var node = domConstruct.create("div", {"class":"container"}, refNode, "after");
// move the refNode inside our wrapping node
domContruct.place(refNode, node);
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty approach looks like this:

```js
element.outerHTML = '<div>' + element.outerHTML + '</div>';
```

No need for any libraries. Note, this will create a new object under the hood, so you have to retrieve `element` again to get the surrounding element, in case you need it afterwards.

Overall, it's handy, because you do not have to remove the old element and insert the new one.

I also came up with a [similar approach to replace the tag name and preserve attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860417/javascript-change-html-tag-type/68138024#68138024), which might be interesting for one or another.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it was in 2013, but these days, dojo's NodeList-manipulate functionality allows you to do it quite easily.

Given:

```
<b>one</b>
<b>two</b>
```

Use:

```
require(["dojo/query", "dojo/NodeList-manipulate"], function(query){
  query("b").wrap("<div><span></span></div>");
});
```

Output:

```
<div><span><b>one</b></span></div>
<div><span><b>two</b></span></div>
```

This example is take from the documentation [here](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/NodeList-manipulate.html#wrap).