# Mail validation angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an issue with angularjs and the email input type.

I want to create dynamic inputs with a directive, but the input type validation might be buggy. 
Here is the jsfiddle of my test
http://jsfiddle.net/NPCHr

To avoid some trouble I have to use this trick

```
element.find('input')[0].type = input.type;
```

When I had a second character in the input the model field disappears (In the html panel)

I don't know why is this a bug or am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your directive is not that e-mail validation doesn't work but the fact that dynamic `type` attribute is not supported by AngularJS (and jQuery BTW). This is due to the fact that IE doesn't allow changing input's type on-the-fly ([Changing the <input> type in IE with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566394/changing-the-input-type-in-ie-with-javascript)).

This topic was discussed in great details on the AngularJS mailing list, here is the reference: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/Itl-fYzeF18 where someone had exactly the same problem as yours.

The way out of this situation is to manually compile a template using the `$compile` service. Unfortunately this is not trivial, you can see evidence of some experiments here: https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui/pull/191

An alternative, simpler approach is to use `ngInclude` directive to include different inputs based on their type. Yet another possibility is to use the compile function and manually transform template's markup. But yes, all of those techniques require several lines of non-trivial code.