# How to change input type dynamically using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is the my html code:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="multiOptions" />IsForMultioptions

<input type="radio" value="1" name="option">option1

<input type="radio" value="2" name="option">option2
```

If I select checkbox i.e. multiOptions then all radio buttons should be convert into checkboxes.
and If I uncheck the checkbox i.e. multiOptions then all checkboxes should convert in radio buttons.
thanks in advance.

Comment: It will not work in Internet Explorer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566394/changing-the-input-type-in-ie-with-javascript

Comment: Then what is the solution for it? There should be something by that we can achieve this.

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to actually remove and recreate the elements, because IE doesn't let you change the `type` of an `input` after it's created.

jQuery makes this fairly easy with [`replaceWith`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith):

```
$("selector for the input to change").replaceWith('<input type="checkbox">');
```

So for instance:

```
$('input[type="radio"][name="option"]').each(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith('<input type="checkbox" name="option" value="' + this.value + '">');
});
```

Or if the values may contain characters requiring entities:

```
$('input[type="radio"][name="option"]').each(function() {
    var rep = $('<input type="checkbox" name="option">');
    rep.attr("value", this.value);
    $(this).replaceWith(rep);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of replacing the elements you can have two groups of which one is hidden depending on the checkbox:

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="multiOptions">IsForMultioptions</input>
<div id="radios">
    <input type="radio" value="1" name="option">option1</input>
    <input type="radio" value="2" name="option">option2</input>
</div>
<div id="checkboxes">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="option">option1</input>
    <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="option">option2</input>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#checkboxes').hide();

  $('#multiOptions').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('#radios').hide();
      $('#checkboxes').show();
    }
    else {
      $('#radios').show();
      $('#checkboxes').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/9NkVC/).