# jqueryUi autocomplete html and desgin

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm thinking of adding jqueryUi autocomplete to my site, few questions I can't find an answer to:
- Can I remove/replace the the ul tag which holds the responses? I managed to replace the li tags with tr but those are not suppose to be inside a ul tag

Answer (score 0):

Please refer following link: may be this is useful for you.

[How to change input type dynamically using jquery or javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16538878/how-to-change-input-type-dynamically-using-jquery-or-javascript)

Comment: doesnt help since i need to modify it before loading and not after