# Transform input type text to password

Tags: jquery, attr

I want to change the input type to password when I click on it. I tried this:

```
<input name="pin" id="cp_serv" type="text" class="pin_v" value="Insert PIN Please" onclick="this.value='';$(this).attr('type','password');"/>
```

I tried to use the jQuery function `attr` to change this on the `click` event, but nothing is happening.

Is this the right way to do it or is this possible?

Comment: Seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/H24VP/

Comment: Instead of a JavaScript workaround use the `placeholder`-attribute. [Browser support](http://caniuse.com/input-placeholder).

Comment: @j08691 Did you try it in IE? If you read the question rink.attendant linked, it says that IE doesn't allow it.

Comment: People read the duplicate link... This wouldn't work on IE8

Comment: The problem in firefox i can´t do works fine , no show dots of password when i go to do click

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This will work

```
$('input').on('click', function () {
   $(this).attr('type', 'password'); 
});
```

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kPJbU/)**

**Update**

For IE read accepted answer for this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566394/changing-the-input-type-in-ie-with-javascript).

Comment: Did you test it in IE?

Comment: Please test this on IE 8

Comment: Might want to just limit it to the `cp_serv` input box or every input on the page will change. And also you might want to check out [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Comment: I don't have IE. I am Mac user. Could you please test it if it works?

Comment: It doesn't. I was just being polite :)

Comment: Careful on this, I thought implementing this would be good way around the chrome autofill problem, but when the type is changed from text to password, it will autoselect the first option in the autofill list.

Answer (score -2):

`jquery.Attr` should work the way that you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/7UA95/

**UPDATE**

This one when you click on it:

http://jsfiddle.net/7UA95/1/

Comment: According to the duplicate question, IE doesn't allow you to change input type.